# Validar fechas Java - No aceptar fechas mayores a la fecha actual

Tags: java, date

¿Cómo puedo validar si fechaEleccion es mayor que la fecha actual? La idea es para que el usuario inserte la fecha de nacimiento, y para ello he usado la libreria JCalender.

```
Date fechaEleccion = (Date) nuevoMonitor.date_elegir.getDate(); 
String fechaEntrada = "";
if (fechaEleccion != null) {
fechaEntrada = formatoFecha.format(fechaEleccion); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías usar un método cómo el siguiente:

```java
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
        
        calendario.set(2021, 11, 31);
        Date fechaEleccion = calendario.getTime();
        
        if (esDespuesDeHoy(fechaEleccion)) {
            // Has tus acciones, podrías lanzar una exepción o informar de un error.
            System.out.println("fechaEleccion es despues de hoy!!");
            //ejemplo
            throw new Exception("La fecha de entrada no puede ser superior a la fecha actual.");
        } 
        
        // Continua tu código, aquí ya aseguramos que la fecha es anterior.
        System.out.println("Continuando...");
        
    }
    
    public static boolean esDespuesDeHoy(Date entrada) {
        return entrada.getTime() > Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
    }
}
```

`Calendario` lo usé para simular la entrada que tienes en `nuevoMonitor.date_elegir.getDate();` al fin de cuentas lo que hace esa linea es darme un objeto tipo `java.util.Date`. Entonces solo puse a `fechaEleccion` con el valor 31 de diciembre del 2021 (en el segundo parametro del  `calendario.set` es un `int` de base 0, diciembre es 11 y enero es 0) y con el método estatico `boolean esDespuesDeHoy(Date)` me retorna `true` si la fecha de entrada es después de hoy. Con eso ya puedes hacer la lógica de tu software.

En el ejemplo lanzo una excepción de tipo `Exception` y por eso puedes ver que en la declaración del método `main` tuve que añadir `throws Exception` pero es solo un ejemplo, ya tu lo manejarás como lo veas conveniente.

Consejo: no uses `java.util.Date` muchos de sus metodos han sido declarados obsoletos (deprecated) en las nuevas versiones de java. Hay otras alternativas mejores, cómo `java.time.LocalDate`.

Saludos!!

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por explicar con tanto detalle.

Comment: ¿Habría alguna forma de no poner  calendario.set(2021, 11, 31); ? Es decir, se trata de una aplicación para la inscripción de usuarios, la persona que compre la aplicación no puede modificar el código, por lo que ¿no podríamos actualizar dicha fecha en función pasan los días?

Comment: Es justamente lo que hace tu línea `(Date) nuevoMonitor.date_elegir.getDate();` ¿No? Interpreto que esa linea obtiene de algún lado lo que eligió el usuario y lo convierte en Date. `calendario.getTime();` hace exactamente eso, convertir algo a Date solo que obviamente el usuario no lo elige, lo elige el programador. Ignora mi Calendar, ya que solo lo uso para convertir fechas a tipo Date. Haz `Date fechaEleccion = (Date) nuevoMonitor.date_elegir.getDate(); ` y usa el método `esDespuesDeHoy` y ya.